# Wiring Input Diagram for a Dual Winding - 2 tap / winding. 2 x 115V and 2 x 12 V

Tags: transformer

I was told by the local electronic parts outlet store that I could use a Tamura Micro PL10-24 to reduce voltage from a 16V AC source to approximatly 12V.  I need assistance with the correct wiring scheme.  The 12V taps are labled 1-3-4 and 6.  The 115V taps are lable 7-9-10 and 12.  It's my understanding that I can use the positive side source to wire to tap 6, Bridge taps 3 and 4 and bride tap 1 and 7.  Use tap 9 to wire to neutral side of source.  Use tap 10 and 12 for output of 12 V. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you supply some more information of what the Tamura Micro PL10-24 is. Such as a datasheet.

Comment: Tamura makes transformers - see here: http://www.tamuracorp.com/index.php?src=directory&view=2006products&srctype=display&id=129813&category=Power%20Transformers&PHPSESSID=655f4d7e5b9f249475557eab589220c3

Answer (score 1):

You have a transformer with two 120V primary windings, and two 12V secondary windings.

From what your saying, you are wiring both secondary windings and one primary winding in series, and then taking the output from the other primary winding?

This will **not** give you 12 VAC from 16VAC input, but it will get you close.

The transformer ratio between primary and secondary is 10:1

With the way you are describing it, you get a ratio of 10+1+1:10, or 12:10, so 16VAC in will give you 16*(10/12) VAC out, or 13.333~ VAC.

Note: You have the primary and secondary backwards. The 120 VAC taps are 1,3,4,6, and the secondary is 7,9,10,12 - See datasheet [here](http://www.tamuracorp.com/clientuploads/pdfs/engineeringdocs/PL10-XX-130B.pdf).

---

It's worth noting that this is a horrible hack, and I really wouldn't recommend doing it unless you have no choice. Also, the transformer will not achieve anything near it's rated power spec in this configuration.

It's probably also a really good idea to lash-up a test rig and check your input and output voltages before soldering the whole affair into place. You may have to reverse the direction of the secondary (e.g. swap pin 7 and 12, though I don't think so).